# how can i insert comment with article by php using id

Tags: php

I am Beginner. I need help, please.
I am having a small problem in the script
I am have in this script ( admin folder) Add contain articles (This page is working to add threads only)
My problem in the Page (read_mor.php)
i make a query with the database to bring news
this is query .

```
<?php 
include ('config/connect_to_mysql.php');
$id = $_GET["id"];
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id= '$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)) {
?>
<?php echo $myrow['title']; ?>
<?php echo $myrow['created_on']; ?>
<?php echo $myrow['categories']; ?>
<?php echo $myrow['description']; ?>
<?php echo $myrow['categories']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

everything is v god

**but when i insert comment in table (comments) 
all comments in table show with any post ..!! **

**i need to insert comment with article by id article**

this page for insert comment

```
<?php
include ('config/connect_to_mysql.php');

$query="INSERT INTO comments (com_id,name,url,email,comment,postid)
      VALUES
      ('', '$_POST[name]' , '$_POST[url]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[comment]', LAST_INSERT_ID(postid))" or die(mysql_error());

if ($query)

$result = mysql_query($query);

{
echo "<strong>Thanks!</strong><p>Your message was successfully sent.</p>";  
}
?>
```

Table in database 
---- >

```
comments



 structure for table `comments`
 (
  `com_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `yes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `postid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`com_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT  
</i>
```

table of posts
------>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `categories` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `post_meta` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `post_robots` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `meta_title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` text NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `imageref` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'published',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=102 ;
```

Comment: FYI, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Also, I don't understand what your issue is.  Does the insert fail?  Why are you checking the truth value of `$query` (which will always evaluate to `true`) instead of `$result`?

Comment: $result Or $query not my problem  .. The problem is when I add a comment process is done successfully, but are not related to the comments threads

Comment: Actually, I'd say it's a significant problem, since `$query` would always return as `true` and you don't seem to be checking to see if your insert was successful.

Comment: Okay Can You tell Me What Can I do :D

Comment: I still don't understand what your issue is.  Is it with the `insert`?

Comment: Okay ( look ) When i do submit comment inserting but when i open the post all comment will show because ID in posts table is not associated with the postid in comment

Comment: now i need when i post comment - comment show with post by id how can i insert postid in comments table with id in posts table and how can show topic with comment : if i used inner join How can i used it .. !!

Comment: I'm sorry, I still have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Ummm.....you're welcome?  I guess?

Comment: Question in another form
how would I be able to have the comment display under the correct post? I have the postid, but I'm at a loss of how to make it the same ID as the blog post if they are in different tables in a database. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that LAST_INSERT_ID() works correctly for auto_increment fields, which postid is not. Also you shouldn't be using LAST_INSERT_ID() for anything other than your primary key.

Comment: Question in another form how would I be able to have the comment display under the correct post? I have the postid, but I'm at a loss of how to make it the same ID as the blog post if they are in different tables in a database. Thanks again!

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, and you can even do it in one query, but I found that in most applications this would not be practical. What you should try is first getting your postid, assign it to a variable (in PHP) and build the query for the comments based on that (something like WHERE `postid` = {$post_id}).